# Order by Numeric Custom Field Value

Tags: templating

I'm trying to order my entries by a numeric custom field named `score`, some of these values can be `0` but unfortunately, it's not getting ordered at all?

```
{% set users = craft.users.group('influencer').order('score').limit(24) %}

{% if users|length %}
    {% paginate users as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
    {% for user in pageEntries %}
```

/* New Code */

```
  {% set users = craft.users.group('influencer').orderBy('score desc').limit(24) %}

          {% if users|length %}

          {% paginate users as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
          {% for user in pageEntries %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is in Craft 3, you should be using `.orderBy()` instead of `.order()`. Does the following work as expected?

```
{% set users = craft.users.group('influencer').orderBy('score desc').limit(24) %}

{% paginate users as pageInfo, pageUsers %}

{% for user in pageUsers %}
    {{ user.username }} : {{ user.score }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Here it is in the docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/user-queries.html#orderby

Also turn on `devMode` to be sure that no errors are being suppressed.

Comment: I need to limit the array for Pagination to work, I've edited my answer with code but it's still not ordering them correctly.

Comment: How exactly is it ordering them? I just did a local test and this appears to be working.

Comment: Alphabetically for some reason? Could it be empty values?

Comment: Well do any users actually have values store in their `score` field?

Comment: Heh, yeah. 3 out of 5 entries have a user.score

Comment: Then I don't see why it wouldn't work :)

Comment: This is so bizarre!

Comment: My advice would be to test it with entries with the template scaled down to the bare minimum, then troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Could it be that the output is being cached? Does changing the limit make a difference?

Comment: nope, even changing the field that it's sorting on makes little difference. I think this is a bug?

Comment: Think I figured this out - whole numbers work - decimal point numbers, fail.